# How to clear the memory in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, srand

I have written a program to generate a random string,
but when i am calling the function for two/more times,i am getting same random strings.

Please check the code below:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* randomstring(int length);

int main()
{
   char* randomstring(int);
   char *str, *str2;
   str = randomstring(3);
   str2 = randomstring(3);
   printf("final random string is %s and length is %s\n", str, str2);
}

char* randomstring(int length)
{
   int len, len1, i = 0, j = 0;
   char *c;
   char *string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   len = strlen(string);
   len1 = length + 1;
   time_t t;
   c=(char*) calloc(len1, sizeof(char));
   printf("final random string is %d \n", len);
   srand((unsigned) time(&t));
   for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
      j=rand() % len;
      c[i] = string[j];
   }
   c[len1] = '\0';
   return c;
}
```

Output :

```
final random string is 26 
final random string is 26 
final random string is BNQ and length is BNQ
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Move `char* randomstring(int);` at the beginning....

Comment: From now on, please properly indent your code or else no one will be able to read it.

Comment: You should put srand((unsigned) time (NULL)) inside your function

Comment: @stanpines s/able/willing/

Comment: Do you mean clear as in using `free` or do you mean clear as in reset it to a default value?

Comment: Your log statements *are* confusing.

Answer (score 4):

The function `srand` sets the random seed, and if you call it again with the same random seed, it will cause future random calls to return a repeat of the same sequence. So when you call:

```
srand((unsigned) time(&t));
```

it resets the random seed to the wall clock time in *seconds*.  Which means if you call it again after less than a second has elapsed (as you do in your code), it probably resets the seed to the same value, causing you to get the same random string again.

You should only call `srand` *once*, at the start of your program in main, before calling any other function that calls `rand`

Comment: if i remove srand function,so will it give correct output?

Comment: If you remove `srand` completely, the random number generator will be seeded with 0.  So it will give "correct" output, but will give the same output every time you run the program.  Putting the `srand` call in `main` will result in different output each time you run the program (assuming the clock ticks at least one second between runs)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for an allocation like

```
c=(char*) calloc(len1,sizeof(char));
```

later, using

```
c[len1]='\0';
```

is accessing out of bound memory. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, C uses 0-based indexing, so, by saying

```
 c[len1]='\0';
```

you're going [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Then, you should call the PNRG seeder function `srand()` only once, possibly at `main()`. Otherwise, `time()` having a granularity of 1 second, it will seed the PNRG with same value which in turn will cause the `rand()` to produce the same set of *random* numbers again.

That said,

1. [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).
2. `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 in C.

A better and robust way of writing the allocation statement will be

```
c =  calloc( len1, sizeof*c );
```